# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null, category is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

This is just a snippet to use as an example, but I am querying an API and returning the results to an array.  The problem I'm facing is that 99% of the time incident.category.name has a value but occasionally incident.category is null which mean incident.category.name doesn't exist on that record at all.  This results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null.

```
                tableData.push({
                "id": incident[i].id,
                "number": incident[i].number,
                "category": incident[i].category.name,
                })
```

Is there a way that I can have it return the word "null" when category is null?

Comment: if the object is null , how can you read its property ?? I mean, if is null, there is no properties ...

Comment: `incident[i].category == null ? "" : incident[i].category.name`

Comment: Did you check that `incident.category` is not null before accessing it?

Comment: @freedomn-m that worked perfectly, thanks for the quick answer